# org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, propertynotfoundexception

I am having difficulty with a property not found exception in my code. I have followed proper naming conventions with public getters and setters but still receive the exception and I am not sure why. I have searched for a solution without posting high and low. What am I doing wrong? Could it be that I am accessing a list?

Java class Book:

```
public class Book {

private String isbn13;          // International Standard Book Number, unique
private String title;
private String author;
private LocalDate publishDate;  // Date of publish to the website

private double price;

private byte[] content;
private ArrayList<String> tagList;

public ArrayList<String> getTagList() {
    return tagList;
}

public void setTagList(ArrayList<String> tagList) {
    this.tagList = tagList;
}

// Constructor used when no date is specified
public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, byte[] content) {
    this.isbn13 = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publishDate = LocalDate.now();
    this.content = content;
}

// Constructor used when a date is specified
public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, byte[] content, LocalDate publishDate) {
    this.isbn13 = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publishDate = publishDate;
    this.content = content;
}

// Default constructor
public Book() {
    this.isbn13 = null;
    this.title = null;
    this.author = null;
    this.publishDate = LocalDate.now();
    this.content = null;
}

public String getIsbn13() {
    return isbn13;
}

public void setIsbn13(String isbn13) {
    this.isbn13 = isbn13;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public LocalDate getPublishDate() {
    return publishDate;
}

public void setPublishDate(LocalDate publishDate) {
    this.publishDate = publishDate;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public byte[] getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(byte[] content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

}

code from .jsp file

```
<c:forEach var="tag" items="${book.tagList}">
    <c:out value="${tag}" />
</c:forEach>
```

exception thrown:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 
org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: 
/bookPublishingHome.jsp(50,10) '${book.tagList}' The class 
'examples.pubhub.model.Book' does not have the property 'tagList'.
```